# Modal is not shown complete in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have two modal windows in bootstrap one is smaller and another long, both have important data, when I close the first the second one opens, the problem is that when I open the longer window, it does not appear complete, and when the Long window first shows well and completely.

Code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
        Hola Mundo

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="continue">Continue</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal2">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea rows="40"></textarea>    
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                End
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <button id="test">Not work</button>
        <button id="test2">Work</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-8WqyJLuWKRBVhxXIL1jBDD7SDxU936oZkCnxQbWwJVw="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){
            $('#modal1').modal('show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#test2', function(e){
            $('#modal2').modal('show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#continue', function(e){
            $('#modal1').modal('hide');
            $('#modal2').modal('show');
        });        
        </script>                         
    </body>    
</html>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/onkdfjpk/3/

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Check your elements `ID`, you have a conflict in there, multi `id="test2"`, than a button id="test" (not in script). Fix that and it should work. Maybe read the [docs again](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#modals-examples).

Comment: Same, please helpme

Comment: Copy paste the code you see in examples [here](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#modals-examples).

Comment: Done, same error.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are opening a new modal when the first is not completly closed.
You should wait for the first one to be hidden:

```
 $('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#modal2').modal('show');
 });
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/onkdfjpk/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: auto;` to `#modal2` and it would work as what you expected.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e) {
  $('#modal1').modal('show');
});

$(document).on('click', '#test2', function(e) {
  $('#modal2').modal('show');
});

$(document).on('click', '#continue', function(e) {
  $('#modal2').modal('show');
  $('#modal1').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
#modal2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
Hola Mundo
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          Header
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="continue">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <textarea rows="40"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          Footer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="test">Not work</button>
<button id="test2">Work</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's another way but I don't want to change JS part since you can't sure that it always opens `#modal2` after closing `#modal1`.

Comment: The continue button is inside `#modal1` and clicking it will always hide `#modal1`. Opening `#modal2` first does not create issue.

Comment: Depending on the datas within `#modal1`, I think there would be a chance to open another modal.